# onclick event in navigation drawer layout ...where to write java code

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I 've created login signup form in login layout and signup layout respectively in navigation drawer. In signup layout I 've included a button with onclick event. My signupfragment extends fragments...where to write on click method and edittext to string java code?...![button onclick event in signup 
 layout]chrome://history(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFEbB.jpg)! [SignupFragment extends Fragment where to write edittext to string java code and on click java code ]chrome://history(https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Hqv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this part on your code? you can handle all the items there in your menu..

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
return true;
}
```

Comment: I 've this onNavigationItemSelected in my main activity only??

Comment: Check this one
http://chrisrisner.com/Using-Fragments-with-the-Navigation-Drawer-Activity